# ggplot legend alpha is completely transparent

Tags: r, ggplot2

For some reason, the alpha legend on my plot is showing as totally transparent when it should be faded red.

```
 geom_boxplot(
  aes(x=OldAdjuster, ymin=bottom,lower=lower,middle=middle,upper=upper,max=top, fill="red", alpha = percentClosed),
  stat="identity")
```

The fill and alpha on my box plot works fine, but it's as if there is no "red" fill on my legend where it should be showing how different values of alpha should look.  Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a minimal, self-contained example for troubleshooting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently you are `mapping` fill to  `"red"`, which means it is creating a variable `"red"` and coincidentally the first default fill colour is a shade of red.

Aesthetics may be `mapped` (passed to the `mapping` argument within a `call` to `aes` or `aes_string`) or `set` (outside `aes`, as named arguments).

If you set `fill = 'red'`, then every thing works as you wish.

A *reproducible* example

```
# modified from ?geom_boxplot
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg))

# incorrect
p + geom_boxplot(aes(alpha = factor(am), fill ='red')) + theme_bw()
```

[image]

```
# the correct approach
p + geom_boxplot(aes(alpha = factor(am)), fill ='red') + theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow. Great answer! Can't believe my mistake.